# Submit Form consisting of partial (asynchronous) views

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I was trying to make a JQuery-Tabcontrol work with asynchronous Tabs.

That tabcontrol is part of a form and the problem is, that the submit doesnt really work with the asynchronous loaded parts of the view model.

My viewmodel is similiar to windows-forms. It consists of controls with children.
Each controls has an editortemplate. I tried to make my tab-control work asynchronously. (It works well synchronously) but this part is keeping me busy since friday.

Using those editor-templates i was required to write a custom model binder. When i put a breakpoint in there, it doesnt get hit for the parts of the view that were loaded on demand. However, i find those values when i digg down into the value providers / the Form collection of the controller. So it definitly receives all data, but it doesnt want to call the Binders for it.

How do I make it call the binders so data entered into one of the tabs is bound to the viewmodel ?

This is the view of the tab-control

```
@model {..}.TabControlViewModel

<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Pages.Count; i++)
    {
      <li>
          @Html.ActionLink(Model.Pages[i].Title, "ShowPartial", new  { formId = Model.FormId, controlId = Model.Pages[i].Id})
      </li>
    }
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is the controllermethod:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> ShowPartial(int formId, int controlId)
    {
        TabPageViewModel tabPage= await FormControlManager.GetTabPage(this, formId, controlId);
        await Task.Delay(1000); // just for testing
        return PartialView(tabPage);
    }
```

View of ShowPartial

```
@model {...}.ControlViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(x => x)
```

---

**Some more detailed info**

The whole Control-Nesting-Idea is based on this tutorial:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2012/04/23/generating-aspnet-mvc-view-controls-according-to-xml-configurations/ (though its not flat but recursive (like windows forms))

So basically everything is a member of FormControl. Which is also returned by the intial Action of the Controller called "Show"

When the user selectes a tab, it gets the reference of the form by passing the formid and also the controlId to get the required TabPage control and returns it. So from dataperspective, the asynchronousparts are allready part of the ViewModel, but arent used initially when rendering. The only thing I need to change to make it work synchronously is the Editor-Template for the TabControl.

Comment: What does your client side code look like? Do you preload any JavaScript or are you using a framework like RequireJS to dynamically load JavaScript?

Comment: By preloading you mean if I load the Bundles? Yes thats how i dot it. Just loading the Javascript-Bundles (Jquery, Jquery ui) so that TabControls, datepickers and stuff are working.

Comment: Partials can have their own class bindings. When doing things of this nature, I tend to bind the partial to either the same View-Model as the parent (and pass the view model), or to sub-classes within the parent View-Model (passing those).

Comment: @DaveAlperovich Im not sure if I understand you. Can you show an example ?

Comment: Do you know how to pass a model to a partial? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879940/object-reference-error-using-partial-views/14880123#14880123

Comment: I got a view called ShowPartial which only calls EditorFor for the passed view Model. It works it displays the TabPagecontent fine. So I guess i do know or I am not getting your point here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work by modifying some things:

First of all i extended my ModelBinder so it handles List, i acchieved this by overriding BindProperty after I read myself through the sourcecode of the [DefaultModelBinder](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs)

```
public class ControlViewModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult formIdResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("FormId");
        if (formIdResult == null)
            return null;
        long formId = long.Parse(formIdResult.AttemptedValue);

        ValueProviderResult controlIdResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".Id");
        if (controlIdResult == null)
            return null;

        int controlId = int.Parse(controlIdResult.AttemptedValue);
        FormViewModel form;
        ControlViewModel model = FormControlManager.GetControl(formId, controlId, out form);

        if (model == null)
            return null;

        bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, model.GetType());
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }


    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        // need to skip properties that aren't part of the request, else we might hit a StackOverflowException
        string fullPropertyKey = _buildPropName(bindingContext.ModelName, propertyDescriptor.Name);
        if (!bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix(fullPropertyKey))
        {
            return;
        }
        // call into the property's model binder
        object originalPropertyValue = propertyDescriptor.GetValue(bindingContext.Model);
        ModelMetadata propertyMetadata = bindingContext.PropertyMetadata[propertyDescriptor.Name];

        // If it is not an IEnumerable we can make the default Function do its magic
        if (!(originalPropertyValue is IEnumerable<ControlViewModel>))
            base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
        else
        {
            // Else we need to call the BindModel method for each Member of the Sequence.
            int index = 0;
            foreach (ControlViewModel value in (IEnumerable<ControlViewModel>)originalPropertyValue)
            {
                propertyMetadata.Model = value;
                ModelBindingContext innerBindingContext = new ModelBindingContext()
                {
                    ModelMetadata = propertyMetadata,
                    ModelName = fullPropertyKey + String.Format("[{0}]", index++),
                    ModelState = bindingContext.ModelState,
                    ValueProvider = bindingContext.ValueProvider
                };

                BindModel(controllerContext, innerBindingContext);
            }
        }

    }

    static string _buildPropName(string prefix, string propertyName)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
        {
            return propertyName;
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        {
            return prefix;
        }
        else
        {
            return prefix + "." + propertyName;
        }
    }
```

The Second part is, that I had to modify the HtmlHelper for the parts that are meant to be rendered asynchronously.

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorForDynamic<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        where TModel : IAsyncControlWithPrefix
{
    IAsyncControlWithPrefix model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;
    htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = model.PrefixForPartialRender + htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
    return htmlHelper.EditorFor(expression);
}

public static string GetFullText<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    return htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
}
```

This makes sure that those asynchronous rendered parts still create the complete nested string that looks liks :

Children[0].Pages[0].Rows[0].Cells[0].Text
instead of just Rows[0].Cells[0].Text

This is the Interface

```
public interface IAsyncControlWithPrefix
{
    string PrefixForPartialRender { get; set; }
}
```

I my case each TabPage implements this Interface so i can load every tab page asynchronously.

The Tabpages need to get the PrefixAssigned, which happens in the TabControlView

Like this:

```
@model {...}.TabControlViewModel

<div class="tabs">
<ul>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Pages.Count; i++)
    {
      <li>
          @Html.ActionLink(Model.Pages[i].Title, "ShowPartial", new  { formId = Model.FormId, controlId = Model.Pages[i].Id})
          @{ Model.Pages[i].PrefixForPartialRender = Html.GetFullText(m => m.Pages[i]);}
      </li>
    }
</ul>
</div>
```

Well and now it works like a charm. It can submit data from different asynchronously loaded Tabs at once. Pretty nice.